# Why are some songs notated with bpm in minims instead of crotchets?

Tags: sheet-music

A few songs I am learning in 4/4 time have the bpm up at the top of the piece in minims (half notes) instead of the usual crotchet (quarter note) beats. For example one pop song I am learning says 80 minim beats per minute which would be 160 crotchet beats per minute. Why not just say 160 crotchet beats per minute then? Also, some of the pieces are in cut time and I am trying to understand if there is a relationship between the two.

Comment: Take some time to think about what accents the composer wanted.

Comment: See 2/2 vs 4/4. Note also that conducting 2/2 at 80 BPM for a minim is more comfortable than 4/4 at 160 BPM for a crotchet.